# Set match mode on SphinxQl in sphinxsearch

Tags: search, sphinx, sphinxql

I use SphinxQl, I got query like this

```
SELECT `id`, WEIGHT() as relevance FROM `rt_table` WHERE MATCH('dubai')
```

I want to set match mode extended to make search by * (wildcard) like

```
SELECT `id`, WEIGHT() as relevance FROM `rt_table` WHERE MATCH('dub*')
```

to get all data which contains "dub" substring.

```
min_word_len    =   1
min_prefix_len  =   2
```

and this is part of my config of index .
I have tried set min_infix_len=2 but it does not help
Problem is that I can not make wildcard search *.

Please help someone!

Comment: Did you recreate the index after changing the config? You need to delete (or TRUNCATE) the index, and reinsert all the data again. (assuming its a RT index, if a standard disk index, it will need to be recreated via indexer)

Answer (score -1):

If you use SphinxQl you need to just make some changes in index config

```
min_word_len    =   2   
min_infix_len   =   2   
enable_star =   1   
dict        =   keywords
```

and you can search using wildcard

Comment: THis answer is misleading, its not really correct, dont need to make these changes at all. Don't need to change min_word_len. Can use wildcards with min_prefix_len, only need infix if want wildcards at both ends of the word. Don't need enable_star=1 - its the detail anyway. And don't need dict=keywords (its the default , and infix/prefix indexing does work with dict=crc anyway)